# Context-sensitive Grammar for a^nb^nc^n

Tags: computation-theory, finite-automata, turing-machines, context-sensitive-grammar

Is the following CSG for a^nb^nc^n correct?

```
S->aSbC|abc
Cb->bC
C->c
```

If not please explain why?

Comment: This question is better suited to https://cs.stackexchange.com/. Stack Overflow is for questions about coding.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/135633/context-sensitive-grammar-for-the-language-anbncn-mid-n%E2%89%A51

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/context-sensitive-grammar-csg-and-language-csl/

Answer (score 1):

Productions:
`S -> abc | aAbc`
`Ab -> bA`
`Ac -> Bbcc`
`bB -> Bb`
`aB -> aa | aaA`

Solution:

S → aAbc
→ abAc
→ abBbcc
→ aBbbcc
→ aaAbbcc
→ aabAbcc
→ aabbAcc
→ aabbBbccc
→ aabBbbccc
→ aaBbbbccc
→ aaabbbccc

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).